# Nest level of a list

Tags: python, recursion

```
def nest_level(L):
    '''Return the maximum "nesting level" of nested list L, that is, how many
    levels of sub-lists are in L, at the "deepest" point within L. For example, 
    nest level([1, [[], [[2]]], ’three’]) should return 4 because element 2 is 
    in a list ([2]) within a list ([[2]]) within a list ([[], [[2]]]) 
    within the original list. 
    '''
    if type(L) != list:
        count = 0
    elif L == []:
        count = 1
    else:
        if type(L[0]) == list:
            count = 1
            count = count + nest_level(L[0])
        else:
            count = 0
            count = count + nest_level(L[1:])
    return count
```

Nested list are so confusing to trace, I thought I had it but i was wrong. This returns 3 and should return 4 for the example given. Am I on the right track? Is there a better / easier way to do this? Is there a small fix that would make my function work?

Comment: Try several more examples. Do you see a pattern in the output?

Comment: I tried >>> nest_level([[[3]]]) and it returns 3 like it should, but then the example output gets 3 when it should return 4. So I think this is an algorithm mistake

Comment: What was the output? What should it be?

Comment: Try some more examples. I suggest starting with the simplest one you can think of and them gradually make then more complex.

Comment: nest_level([2]) ->
1 # right
nest_level([[2]]) ->
2 # right
nest_level([[],[[2]]]) ->
2   # wrong. It seems I'm messing up here, thx ill try something

Comment: There are multiple problems in your code. I'm going to give you a few pointers: 1) You can't find the _maximum_ nesting level simply by doing additions. There should probably be a `max(...)` somewhere in your code. 2) Even if the first element is a list, if you want to find the _maximum_ you still have to look at all the other elements.

Comment: I'm trying to practise recursion and using max() isn't allowed in this exercise, but I could make a helper max function using recursion

Comment: Hint: worry only about L itself. Do not look at L[0].

Comment: @Ali89 max() does not require recursion. In fact, I would not create a separate max() function.

Comment: It will help if you step away from the computer and work some examples by hand. After you do a few, write step by step instructions how to perform the calculation. Do this in your native language and do not worry about python syntax nor about recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a Python version, closely dealing with the already given comments and answers:

```
def nest_level(obj):

    # Not a list? So the nest level will always be 0:
    if type(obj) != list:
        return 0

    # Now we're dealing only with list objects:

    max_level = 0
    for item in obj:
        # Getting recursively the level for each item in the list,
        # then updating the max found level:
        max_level = max(max_level, nest_level(item))

    # Adding 1, because 'obj' is a list (here is the recursion magic):
    return max_level + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could think of the problem like this:

1. The nesting level of something that is not a list is defined to be 0.
2. The nesting level of an empty list is defined to be 1.
3. The nesting level of a list (with elements) is 1 + the maximum nesting level of all the elements in it.

So you have three cases to handle, with the third involving taking the maximum of the result of finding the nesting level of each of the elements in the list.

If you convince yourself that this is a valid set of rules that works (by testing it out by hand on some input), you should be able to translate this into a Python function quite simply.

Answer (score 0):

You need to recurse on *all* of the items in each list, and pick the maximum nesting you find:

```
def nest_level(lst):
    if not isinstance(lst, list):
        return 0
    if not lst:
        return 1
    return max(nest_level(item) for item in lst) + 1
```

If you can't use the builtin `max` function in the recursive step, you can find the maximum yourself:

```
max_level = nest_level(lst[0])
for item in lst[1:]:
    level = nest_level(item)
    if level > max_level:
        max_level = level
return best + 1
```

If you want to stick to a purely recursive implementation with no explicit loops, you can do that too:

```
def nest_level(lst):
    if not isinstance(lst, list):
        return 0
    if not lst:
        return 1
    return max(nest_level(lst[0]) + 1, nest_level(lst[1:]))
```

That version can be done without `max` too:

```
def nest_level(lst):
    if not isinstance(lst, list):
        return 0
    if not lst:
        return 1
    first_level = nest_level(lst[0]) + 1
    rest_level = nest_level(lst[1:])
    return first_level if first_level >= rest_level else rest_level
```