# How to get the deepest list in list with abstract element?

Tags: python, list, numpy

Here I have some lists with any particular element (`a`, `b`, and `c`)

```
a = [2, 4, [9, 10]]
b = [1, 3, 5, 9, [11, 13, 14, 15, [16, 17, 19, 24]]]
c = [2, 4, [5, 11, 13, [14, 17, 29, [31, 19]]]]

npA = np.array(a, dtype = object)
npB = np.array(b, dtype = object)
npC = np.array(c, dtype = object)
```

I am trying to get the deepest list in each list `a`, `b`, `c`

```
print(npA[-1]) # it shows [9,10]
print(npB[-1][-1]) # it shows [16, 17, 19, 24]
print(npC[-1][-1][-1]) # it shows [31, 19]
```

How do get the generalization of this problem? or is there any built-in function of NumPy that can directly handle this?

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42728126/13897851) that correspond to your question, you can shrink the function as you like. It's clear and concise, using recursivity, and without NumPy. It gives you the nested level of a list, then you can access it as you want.

Comment: Your numpy arrays here make little sense because are are mixing scalar and array types in elements.  This completely eliminates the advantages of using numpy.  IMHO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve this recursively, without numpy:

```
from typing import List

def deepest_list(l: List) -> List:
    last_item = l[-1]
    if isinstance(last_item, list):
        return deepest_list(last_item)
    return l
```

output:

```
deepest_list(c)
[31, 19]
```